# python mongodb selection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have following data in mongodb

```
domain1 url1 level processed
domain1 url2 level processed
domain1 url3 level processed
domain1 url4 level processed
domain2 url5 level processed
domain2 url6 level processed
domain2 url7 level processed
domain2 url8 level processed
domain3 url9 level processed
domain3 url10 level processed
domain3 url11 level processed
domain3 url12 level processed
```

`level` is an integer and `processed` is a boolean flag. Each time I need to select only one document of each domain ordered by level. First query should return

```
domain1 url1 level processed
domain2 url5 level processed
domain3 url9 level processed
```

What is the fastest way to do it in mongodb?

Comment: Pelase reformat your post, it's completely unreadable right now.

Comment: Seems that map/reduce can do the job here. I'm not sure if aggregation framework is capable of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate:

```
db.stmp.aggregate( {$sort: {domain: 1}}, 
                   {$group: {_id: '$domain', 
                             url: {$first: '$url'}, 
                             level: {$first: '$level'}, 
                             processed: {$first: '$processed'}})
```

if you create index by sort field (domain), or place a $match before $sort (and index it) - this will be done quickly ...